# Overloading Method in Swift Gives Objective C error

Tags: swift, cloudkit, overloading

I'm trying to extend the `CKRecord` class to allow subscripting. To do so, I've created a new file, called `CKRecordHelper`, and done:

```
extension CKRecord {
    subscript(key: String) -> AnyObject! {
        get {
            return self.objectForKey(key)
        }
        set(newValue) {
            self.setObject(newValue as? CKRecordValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting an error on the `get` and `set` lines, which reads:

> Subscript getting with Objective-C selector 'objectoForKeyedSubscript:' conflicts with method 'objectForKeyedSubscript' with the same Objective-C selector.

How do I fix this? From what I understand, Objective-C doesn't allow method overloading, but I'm using Swift. Ultimately, I'm just looking to allow a `CKRecord` to allow subscripting on it.

Comment: From my testing in Playgrounds, CKRecord already has subscripting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@nonobjc` attribute to hide the method from ObjC runtime so Swift compiler doesn't need to worry about compatibility with ObjC code.

```
extension CKRecord {
    @nonobjc subscript(key: String) -> AnyObject! {
        get {
            return self.objectForKey(key)
        }
        set(newValue) {
            self.setObject(newValue as? CKRecordValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I appreciate the help.